# Formik javascript syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have difficulty understanding some syntaxes usually have been used while working with Formik. I think many people have such issues when starting with react and formik. Please take a look at this code:

```
export default Formik({
  mapPropsToValues: (props) => ({ 
    email: props.user.email,
    username: props.user.username,
    imaginaryThingId: props.user.imaginaryThingId,
  }),

  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    email: Yup.string().email('Invalid email address').required('Email is required!'),
    username: Yup.string().required('This man needs a username'),
  }),

  handleSubmit: (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // submit them do the server. do whatever you like!
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 1000);
  },
})(UserForm);
```

Question #1: What does `export default Formik({})` do? is it a function definition?

Question #2: `validationSchema: Yup.object()` What is this? using colons outside object definition!?

Question #3: What part of code does execute first?

Comment: All of these questions are plain javascript and in no way related to Formik or React

Comment: can u give me a keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you spend some time getting more familiar with JavaScript first, as these questions are really not specific to React or Fromik. Essentially, `withFormik(options)` returns a function that takes a React component as input and returns an enhanced component that manages form state internally. The following is basically what you have above, written in a way that should answer your questions.

```
const UserForm = /* base form component */
const mapPropsToValues = /* props mapper */
const validationSchema = /* validation schema */
const handleSubmit = /* submit handler */
const formikOptions = { mapPropsToValues, validationSchema, handleSubmit }
const EnhancedUserForm = withFormik(formikOptions)(UserForm)

export default EnhancedUserForm
```